# Git stash: How to see if there are stashed changes in a branch

Tags: git, git-stash

Let's say i'm in a branch off of master, called "my_new_stuff".  I have a feeling i might have stashed something in there.  I'm worried that if I do `git stash pop` and i *didn't* stash anything it's going to shove a load of unwanted crap into my working folder.

Can i see if there are stashed changes without unstashing them?

thanks, max

Comment: There's a `git stash show` subcommand that seems like it would be useful here.

Comment: @gcbenison - i tried that in my branch and it shows three files.  Then i switched to master and tried there and it shows the same three files.  How can i see which branch they are stashed in?  Are stashes linked to a specific branch?

Comment: Stashes are not linked to any branch.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The stash stores snapshots in the same way that commits do. You can see the contents of the stash with

```
git stash list
```

You can reference those snapshots with the `stash@{N}` notation or use the hashes shown. You can use any of Git's commands that work on commits on stashes. For example

```
git diff master stash@{0}
```

will show you what the most recent stash would add/remove to the `master` branch if you applied it there.

Answer (score 10):

Not quite an answer as such, but a little script I made using Peter Lundgren's answer, above, which i find very useful:  when I switch branches it tells me if I have stashed changes.

```
in .git/hooks/post-checkout

#!/bin/sh
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
stashes=`git stash list | grep "WIP on $branch"`
if [ "$stashes" ]
then
  echo "You have the following stashes for this branch:"
  echo $stashes
fi
```

Comment: I'd like to add (at least on windows) using quotes, `"$stashes"` preserves the newlines.

Comment: You can use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` as a more portable and less fragile way to get the branch name